# Let K be a compact set in a surface, U component of S-K, K'=S-U. K has finitely many components. Does every component of K' contains a component of K?

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, curves-and-surfaces, surfaces, path-connected

Let $S$ be a compact connected surface. Let $K$ be a compact subset of $S$ and suppose that $K$ has a finite number of connected components.
Let $U$ be a connected component of $S \setminus K$ and consider $K'= S \setminus U$.
We have that $K \subset K'$, and therefore every component of $K$ is contained in some component of $K'$.
Is it true that every component of $K'$ contains at least one component of $K$?
My feeling is that the answer is yes, but I can not prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Since $S$ is locally connected, every connected component of the open set $S\setminus K$ is open in $S$. Denote the connected components other than $U$ as $\{V_i\}_{i\in I}$. Thus $S=K\sqcup U\sqcup(\sqcup_{i\in I}V_i)$ where, on the right, the subsets are disjoint, and $U$ and $V_i$'s are open while $K$ is closed. The goal is to show that every connected component $C$ of $K'=S\setminus U=K\sqcup (\sqcup_{i\in I}V_i)$ intersects $K$. Otherwise, $C$ is a connected subset included in the disjoint union $\sqcup_{i\in I}V_i$ of open subsets. Thus it must be included in $V_{i_*}$ for some $i_*\in I$. On the other hand, $C$ is a maximal connected subset of $K'$. We conclude that $C=V_{i_*}$. This is a contradiction: $C$, being a connected component, is a closed subset of the compact set $K'$, hence it is closed in $S$, while $V_{i_*}$ is an open subset of $S$. But $S$ was assumed to be connected.

Comment: I couldn't see $C=V_{i_*}$. Nice.